# Connect R to DB ORA -12560

Tags: r, odbc, dbi

I've the error `ORA - 12560` when I try connect to Oracle DB installed on VM.

> sql*plus, pl/sql, excel - connect successfully

Сonnection code in R

```
con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), driver ='Oracle in instantclient_19_14',
dns = "user", encoding = "windows-1251",PWD ="qazedcwsx")
#--- output Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: IM006: [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
```

> sql*plus I can connect only if after the password I write @sid, in R same method not working

Help please =(

Answer (score 1):

Connected ! =)

```
con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
.connection_string = "Driver={Oracle in nstantclient_19_14};Dbq=XE;Uid=user;Pwd=qazedcwsx;)
```